# Animation without xml (own function)

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to create an animation based on a certain method.
The function is used to zoom in without losing image quality.
It also has to be possible to edit the speed of the animation

How can i do this?

Comment: Search for OldNineAnimations on google.

Comment: http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the animationbuilder class and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try  this :

```
AnimationSet animationset = new AnimationSet( true );
Animation animation= new TranslateAnimation( -100, 0, 0, 0); 
animation.setDuration( 700 );
animationset.addAnimation( animation);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html